# 2 identical mysql select queries in if statement, first works second does not

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 mysql select queries within a PHP if statement:

```
             if ($chooselocn =="") {

             $query = "
             SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
             FROM $table 
             LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
             ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
             WHERE
             $where_no_and
             AND 
             (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
             ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
             ";
             }
             else {

             $query = "
             SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
             FROM $table
             LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
             ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
             WHERE
             $where_no_and
             AND
             outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint
             AND 
             (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
             ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
             ";
              }
```

The first query works but the second returns this error message:

Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND   outcodepostcodes.lat <= 51.491239000000000 AND (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR' at line 8

Even if I remove the:

```
AND
outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint
```

from the 2nd query making the two identical I still get similar error msg in the second.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would guess the problem is with `$where_no_and`.  In my experience, about 95% of syntax errors in such code are obvious when your print the SQL *after* variable substitution.

Comment: No, this is used in both queries (and in dozens of other scripts) and is not the problem. It is simply: $where_no_and = rtrim($where, 'AND '); and $where is a listing of conditions.

Comment: Can you show us the value of $where_no_and?, or $where

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments. I will investigate further tomorrow along those lines

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, thank you for being the first to respond in the right direction

Comment: @David Lavieri, thank you for the useful suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the variable `$where_no_and` causes the issue.

It seems like it is empty causing the `WHERE` statement to be followed by the `AND`.

So this line:

```
WHERE $where_no_and AND outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint AND (hide='0'...
```

is like this:

```
WHERE AND outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint AND (hide='0'...
```

The WHERE AND is not valid syntax.

Even after you removed the part:

```
AND outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint
```

Your line would look like this:

```
WHERE $where_no_and AND (hide='0'...
```

Which would result in this:

```
WHERE AND (hide='0'...
```

Again you have `WHERE AND` which is not valid syntax.

Try to make sure that the `$where_no_and` variable is not null or empty.

If your business logic says that this variable COULD be empty then you have to write a couple of more lines of code to handle this case.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you very much for such a lucid answer. I will investigate further tomorrow along those lines

Comment: a MASSIVE thank you for the very lengthy, detailed and exhaustive explanation of EXACTLY what was going on.

Comment: a massive thank you for the very lengthy, detailed and exhaustive explanation of EXACTLY what was going on.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer as the very best but don't know how to do it. I tried clicking the grey arrow on the LHS but it keeps staying at zero

Comment: Would you like to select it as acceptable answer? If yes, the you can click on the tick (V symbol) underneath the 0 and the arrows.. Otherwise is ok..

Don't worry about it!

Comment: Thanks. I have done it and have learnt something new. It wasn't just an acceptable answer, it was the best answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an empty `$where_no_and` variable, thus your second query gets to contain `... WHERE AND ...` which is not valid SQL

Comment: thank you very much. I will investigate further tomorrow along those lines

Comment: thank you for being the first to explain the crux of the problem

Comment: @TudorConstanttin, thank you for being the first to explain the crux of the problem

Comment: Well, Gordon Linoff mentioned the idea first, in a comment to the question, bu I only saw his comment after writing my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but a way to find the bug.

Just put a `var_dump($query)` after the `if()`. It's impossible to tell without knowing what the variables actually contain. The dump will be before the query is executed, so you'll see very well what is going on there.

If the query is still apparently correct post the dump here and we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Why do `if/then` if the queries are supposed to be identical regardless of the condition?

That said, your variables that form the query are probably different depending on the value of `$chooselocn`. I would start by dumping the actual query into debugging log or the browser as well as the variables that compose it and it would shed some light.

I should also add the standard warning about watching out for SQL injections.

Comment: "I would start by dumping the actual query into debugging log or the browser as well as the variables that compose it and it would shed some light.". Can you give me a hint as to how to do this? Queries are not identical because of the AND
outcodepostcodes.lat <= $latpoint in the 2nd query. This latter is actually a simplified proxy for a haversine distance calculation, just to try to get anything to work.

Comment: Sorry, but I am returning to this programming after a 3 year absence so am finding it a little heavy going

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, thank you, thank you and a MASSIVE THANK YOU to every one who replied to my question!!!!

@Gordon Linoff, thank you for being the first to respond in the right direction

@David Lavieri, thank you for the useful suggestion

@Tudor Constantin, thank you for being the first to explain the crux of the problem

@pid, thank you for the useful suggestion

@user2399432, a massive thank you for the very lengthy, detailed and exhaustive explanation of EXACTLY what was going on.

While everyone pointed me in the right direction, and unfortunately I was busy elsewhere to follow up on those early suggestions, I must upvote @user2399432 for going to all that trouble to make absolutely sure that it all sunk in and there were no two ways about it.

Just as background info, this is an extremely old site I have come back to work on, after a three year absence from coding, and I noticed that I had the following lines of code in this particular script:

```
///THIS IS THE CRUCIAL LINE BELOW:
$where_no_and = rtrim($where, 'AND ');
///End of crucial line and then TEST
//var_dump($where_no_and);//VERY USEFUL DIAGNOSTIC! INDISPENSIBLE! MUST  RETAIN! DO NOT DELETE!
//echo "#6 City is:".$lc_city;//USEFUL DIAGNOSTIC
```

So I must have had the same problem those many years ago and dealt with it accordingly using var_dump($where_no_and);

Be that as it may, I was well and truly stuck this time round and your valuable help has knocked down the barricades, SO THANK YOU TO ALL!